# Can this SQL Query be optimized

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have got below SQL query in Procedure, can this more optimized for best results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      [PUBLICATION_ID] as n
     ,[URL] as u 
  FROM [LINK_INFO]
  WHERE Component_Template_Priority > 0 
    AND PUBLICATION_ID NOT IN (232,481) 
ORDER BY URL
```

Please suggest, is using NOT Exists is better way in this.

Thanks

Comment: Only RDBMS is fine...no schema and indexing...looking to best implementation

Comment: @MS : you need to state  the RBDMS. I wasn't inquiring the state of it!

Comment: @Mitch, what you are asking me? and what information more you required, this the proc and I just want suggestion can we optimized more further

Comment: Which database are you running this on? Oracle, MySql?

Comment: @Mitch: [***"How does the Heisenberg compensator work?"**  **"It works very well, thank you."***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transporter_%28Star_Trek%29)

Comment: Can we use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN in above query, if yes please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use NOT EXISTS.  Just going from the code above you probably shouldn't, but it's technically possible.  As a general rule; a very small, quickly resolved set (two literals would definitely apply) will perform better as a NOT IN than as a NOT EXISTS.  NOT EXISTS wins when NOT IN has to do enough comparisons against each row that the correlated subquery for NOT EXISTS (which stops at the first match) resolves more quickly.

This assumes that the comparison set cannot include NULL.  Otherwise NOT IN and NOT EXISTS do not return the same results because NOT IN ( NULL, ...) always returns NULL and therefore no rows whereas NOT EXISTS excludes rows for which it finds a match and NULL won't generate a match and so won't exclude the row.

A third way to compare two sets for mismatches is with an OUTER JOIN.  I don't see a reason to go into that from what we've got so far, so I'll let that one go for now.

A definitive answer would depend on a lot of variables (hence the comments on your question)...

1. What is the cardinality (number of different values) of the publication_id column?
2. Is there an index on the column?
3. How many rows are in the table?
4. Where did you get the values in your NOT IN clause?
5. Will they always be literals or are they going to come from parameters or a subquery?

... just to name a few.  Of course, the best way to find out is by writing the query different ways and looking at execution times and query plans.

**EDIT**  Another is with set operators like EXCEPT.  Again, probably overkill to go into that.

Comment: Thanks, Please see my comments below:1) What is the cardinality (number of different values) of the publication_id column?
MS>> It can be more than 250
2) Is there an index on the column?
MS>> PUBLICATION_ID is indexed
3) How many rows are in the table?
MS>>More than 50000 records
4) Where did you get the values in your NOT IN clause?
MS>> I don't want values from these two publication_id.
5) Will they always be literals or are they going to come from parameters or a subquery?
MS>>Always be fixed.

Please suggest!!

Comment: If you will always want to exclude just those two, use NOT IN with the literals.  Unless those two values filter most of the table, two comparisons against a table scan that returns almost all of the table is likely as good as it's going to get.  If excluding those two values filters most of the table away then you might want to try another technique.  Are the publication_id's somewhat evenly distributed?